# Ubuntu auto-upgrade to newest version

Tags: upgrade, versions

I remember the Ubuntu version I initially installed is 14.xx, and later it seemed to upgrade automatically when new version is available, so that the version I am now running is 15.04. However, after that it seems that it won't upgrade automatically. I think the newest version of Ubuntu is already 16.xx, but mine is still 15.04. Can anyone tell me why? And what should I do if I want to upgrade to the newest version manually?

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone tell me why?

Upgrades have not, are not and never will be automatic. It always needs a manual confirmation or for you to switch repositories.

> And what should I do if I want to upgrade to the newest version manually?

- check 'software & updates' and the 'updates' section and check that all the update are set to on. Bottom one is for checking for newer releases.

[image]

if this is all correct do a

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

all 3rd party software will be disabled and you need to manually turn these on again.

Comment: I have done exactly what you said. But my Ubuntu is still 15.04. Even worse, my firefox crashes and fails to start. Could you help?

Comment: Can I reinstall firefox manually?

Comment: I've tried to uninstall firefox and then reinstall it in software center, but problem persists!